# Probability of getting all face cards when splitting deck of cards in half

Tags: probability

**Question:** What is the probability of getting all of the face cards in one pile when a standard deck of cards is split into two piles?

**Additional info:** Generally a deck of cards is split into two by putting cards in two different piles one card at a time in an alternating fashion until the entire deck is split into two even piles. A standard deck of cards contains 16 face cards out of 52 total cards. The order of the cards in either pile does not matter, all that matters is that one pile has all the face cards.

**My approach and why I think it is wrong:** I tried solving this problem by calculating the binomial probability ($_nC_xp^x(1-p)^{n-x}$), where $n=26$, $x=16$, and $p=\frac{16}{52}$, which results in $P(x)=0.00087$. I believe this is incorrect because it does not take into account the decreasing number of face cards and total cards as more are put into the two separate piles (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Split into two piles means split half? Each pile has 26 cards?

Comment: Yes, when it is split in half we would end up with 26 cards in each half.

Comment: What you are missing is that the chance of a given card in pile $1$ is $\frac 12$, but as you put more face cards in pile $1$ the chance the next one goes in is lower because you have more free spaces in pile $2$ than pile $1$.  The answers make a good calculation, but this is the intuitive answer.

Comment: Except if you are playing tarot a deck has 12 faces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first half of the deck must contain $26$ of the $36$ non-face cards, or it must contain $16$ face cards and $10$ non-face cards.  $$\frac{\binom{36}{26}+\binom{36}{10}}{\binom{52}{26}}\approx1.025\times10^{-6}$$

Answer (score 1):

There are 16 face cards so the remaining 10 cards in the half deck will have to be non-face cards. There are $\binom{36}{10}$ ways to choose 10 non-face cards from all 36 and $\binom{52}{26}$ ways to choose 26 cards from 52 in total. Therefore, the probability is as follows:

$$ \frac{\binom{36}{10}}{\binom{52}{26}} \approx 5.126 x 10^{-7}$$

Or you can think about it in terms of the other half without any face cards. You'll need to choose 26 non-face cards from the 36:

$$ \frac{\binom{36}{26}}{\binom{52}{26}} \approx 5.126 x 10^{-7}$$

You get the same result.

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you want the multiply sign, use \times.  For arithmetic multiply we prefer using the central dot, which you get with \cdot.  2 \times 2 gives $2 \times 2$ and 2 \cdot 2 gives $2 \cdot 2$

Comment: Thanks. I’m new to StackExchange, and I’m learning MathJax as I go.

Comment: One good way to learn MathJax is to right click on some expression that you want to see how it was done.  A menu will pop up and you can choose Show Math As ->TeX Commands.  I learned a lot that way.  I now use it to get a text version that I can copy for my answer.